# Populate df row value based on column header

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

Appreciate any help.  Basically, I have a poor data set and am trying to make it more useful.

Below is a representation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ("Texas","California","Florida"),
               'Q1 Computer Sales': (100,200,300),
               'Q1 Phone Sales': (400,500,600),
               'Q1 Backpack Sales': (700,800,900),
               'Q2 Computer Sales': (200,200,300),
               'Q2 Phone Sales': (500,500,600),
               'Q2 Backpack Sales': (800,800,900)})
```

I would like to have a df that creates separate columns for the Quarters and Sales for the respective state.

I think perhaps regex, str.contains, and loops perhaps?

[snapshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0AvN.png)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site expects you to do some work, so please show us what you've started on your regex or loops. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df_a = df.set_index('State')

df_a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df_a.columns.str.split(' ', n=1)))

df_a.stack(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        State level_1  Backpack Sales  Computer Sales  Phone Sales
0       Texas      Q1             700             100          400
1       Texas      Q2             800             200          500
2  California      Q1             800             200          500
3  California      Q2             800             200          500
4     Florida      Q1             900             300          600
5     Florida      Q2             900             300          600
```

---

Or we can go further:

```
df_a = df.set_index('State')

df_a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df_a.columns.str.split(' ', n=1)), names=['Quarters','Items'])


df_a = df_a.stack(0).reset_index()


df_a['Quarters'] = df_a['Quarters'].str.extract('(\d+)')

print(df_a)
```

Output:

```
Items       State Quarters  Backpack Sales  Computer Sales  Phone Sales
0           Texas        1             700             100          400
1           Texas        2             800             200          500
2      California        1             800             200          500
3      California        2             800             200          500
4         Florida        1             900             300          600
5         Florida        2             900             300          600
```

Comment: @pandas did this answer help you?